# JIRA, Bitbucket, Jenkins and K8s

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline, jira

Our stack is per the title: JIRA, Bitbucket, Jenkins and Kubernetes. I am trying to figure out a good method to manage the code lifecycle. Currently, we are commiting changes to Bitbucket. JIRA is used for issue tracking. Jenkins is configured with pipelines for building the application and Docker containers, then deploy to Kubernetes. I have Bitbucket configured to trigger build jobs on Jenkins and subsequently deploy to the Kubernetes cluster. However, I only see this being viable for Dev environment lifecycle. I am not sure what would be the best practice to manage deploys to higher environments like Stage or Prod. Some ideas I have seen such as tagging the commits and modifying the Jenkins pipeline to react accordingly when the tag is identified seems hard to manage. For instance if someone inadvertently tagged the commit for Prod, that can trigger an unwanted deployment. Furthermore, there is a disconnect between JIRA and the built Docker artifacts so that we can reference specific tickets to a validated image to deploy. I appreciate everyone's input on this.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is not really the greatest at coordinating deployments to multiple environments. You could add approval stages (using the `input` step) in your jenkins pipeline before stage deployment and before prod deployment. You could include the jira issue key in your git branch name or your commit message, and include this as part of your docker image tag. Though I've only ever seen it work with bamboo, there are theoretically ways to report back to jira (so it will show up on your jira issue) about the progress of your deployment to various environments. Let us know how it turns out!